# What happens if SSL expires

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I generated SSL certificate and using it on Apache and Node.js. My certificate will expire after 3 months. And my server will renew it automatically. But what will happen to Node.js? Will it use new certificate or will try to use old one and fails?

My code:

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var app = require('express')();
var https        = require('https');
var server = https.createServer({ key: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/example/domains/example.com.key'), cert: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/example/domains/example.com.cert') },app);
server.listen(8420);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: It will keep using the old one, since you call `fs.readFileSync` on the file once when the process starts. With the script above you will need to restart the process to load the new file.

Comment: Do you have a suggest for like auto restart or something?

Comment: You could just restart daily or something, as long as you renew your certs more than a day before they expire it will pick up the new one before the old one expires